# raise NotImplementedError NotImplementedError

Tags: python, tornado

I use pycharm to write a python3 web app project using tornado web framework,

The listing service has been built already. I need to build the remaining two components: the user service and the public API layer. The implementation of the listing service can serve as a good starting point to learn more about how to structure a web application using the Tornado web framework.

I am required to use tornado's built in framework for HTTP request.

error occurs at listening ( app.listen(options.port))  when I tried to run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Bill/python/Tornado/99-python-exercise-master/listing_service.py", line 203, in <module>
    app.listen(options.port)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2116, in listen
    server.listen(port, address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 100, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

code:

```
    import tornado.web
import tornado.log
import tornado.options
import sqlite3
import logging
import json
import time

class App(tornado.web.Application):

    def __init__(self, handlers, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(handlers, **kwargs)

        # Initialising db connection
        self.db = sqlite3.connect("listings.db")
        self.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        self.init_db()

    def init_db(self):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()

        # Create table
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'listings' ("
            + "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + "listing_type TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + "price INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + "created_at INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + "updated_at INTEGER NOT NULL"
            + ");"
        )
        self.db.commit()

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def write_json(self, obj, status_code=200):
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        self.set_status(status_code)
        self.write(json.dumps(obj))

# /listings
class ListingsHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        # Parsing pagination params
        page_num = self.get_argument("page_num", 1)
        page_size = self.get_argument("page_size", 10)
        try:
            page_num = int(page_num)
        except:
            logging.exception("Error while parsing page_num: {}".format(page_num))
            self.write_json({"result": False, "errors": "invalid page_num"}, status_code=400)
            return

        try:
            page_size = int(page_size)
        except:
            logging.exception("Error while parsing page_size: {}".format(page_size))
            self.write_json({"result": False, "errors": "invalid page_size"}, status_code=400)
            return

        # Parsing user_id param
        user_id = self.get_argument("user_id", None)
        if user_id is not None:
            try:
                user_id = int(user_id)
            except:
                self.write_json({"result": False, "errors": "invalid user_id"}, status_code=400)
                return

        # Building select statement
        select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM listings"
        # Adding user_id filter clause if param is specified
        if user_id is not None:
            select_stmt += " WHERE user_id=?"
        # Order by and pagination
        limit = page_size
        offset = (page_num - 1) * page_size
        select_stmt += " ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"

        # Fetching listings from db
        if user_id is not None:
            args = (user_id, limit, offset)
        else:
            args = (limit, offset)
        cursor = self.application.db.cursor()
        results = cursor.execute(select_stmt, args)

        listings = []
        for row in results:
            fields = ["id", "user_id", "listing_type", "price", "created_at", "updated_at"]
            listing = {
                field: row[field] for field in fields
            }
            listings.append(listing)

        self.write_json({"result": True, "listings": listings})

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        # Collecting required params
        user_id = self.get_argument("user_id")
        listing_type = self.get_argument("listing_type")
        price = self.get_argument("price")

        # Validating inputs
        errors = []
        user_id_val = self._validate_user_id(user_id, errors)
        listing_type_val = self._validate_listing_type(listing_type, errors)
        price_val = self._validate_price(price, errors)
        time_now = int(time.time() * 1e6) # Converting current time to microseconds

        # End if we have any validation errors
        if len(errors) > 0:
            self.write_json({"result": False, "errors": errors}, status_code=400)
            return

        # Proceed to store the listing in our db
        cursor = self.application.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO 'listings' "
            + "('user_id', 'listing_type', 'price', 'created_at', 'updated_at') "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (user_id_val, listing_type_val, price_val, time_now, time_now)
        )
        self.application.db.commit()

        # Error out if we fail to retrieve the newly created listing
        if cursor.lastrowid is None:
            self.write_json({"result": False, "errors": ["Error while adding listing to db"]}, status_code=500)
            return

        listing = dict(
            id=cursor.lastrowid,
            user_id=user_id_val,
            listing_type=listing_type_val,
            price=price_val,
            created_at=time_now,
            updated_at=time_now
        )

        self.write_json({"result": True, "listing": listing})

    def _validate_user_id(self, user_id, errors):
        try:
            user_id = int(user_id)
            return user_id
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception("Error while converting user_id to int: {}".format(user_id))
            errors.append("invalid user_id")
            return None

    def _validate_listing_type(self, listing_type, errors):
        if listing_type not in {"rent", "sale"}:
            errors.append("invalid listing_type. Supported values: 'rent', 'sale'")
            return None
        else:
            return listing_type

    def _validate_price(self, price, errors):
        # Convert string to int
        try:
            price = int(price)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception("Error while converting price to int: {}".format(price))
            errors.append("invalid price. Must be an integer")
            return None

        if price < 1:
            errors.append("price must be greater than 0")
            return None
        else:
            return price

# /listings/ping
class PingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("pong!")

def make_app(options):
    return App([
        (r"/listings/ping", PingHandler),
        (r"/listings", ListingsHandler),
    ], debug=options.debug)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define settings/options for the web app
    # Specify the port number to start the web app on (default value is port 6000)
    tornado.options.define("port", default=6000)
    # Specify whether the app should run in debug mode
    # Debug mode restarts the app automatically on file changes
    tornado.options.define("debug", default=True)

    # Read settings/options from command line
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    # Access the settings defined
    options = tornado.options.options

    # Create web app
    app = make_app(options)
    app.listen(options.port)
    logging.info("Starting listing service. PORT: {}, DEBUG: {}".format(options.port, options.debug))

    # Start event loop
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error can means that you have to write some function (which name should be in full error message)

Comment: I have updated that

Comment: code works for me without this problem - but when I try to use Firefox and port `6000` then it refused to connect. When I use port `5000` then Firefox connect without problem. As I know some ports can be blocked by system for some protocols - and it is not problem with firewall. Tested on Linux Mint 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.8 made a backwards-incompatible change to the `asyncio` package used by Tornado. Applications that use Tornado on Windows with Python 3.8 must call `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` at the beginning of their main file/function. (as documented on the home page of tornadoweb.org)